# Get latest post from client's Instagram account without authentication

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

All I want to do is show the most recent of our client's Instagram posts on the website we are building for them.

This was possible using only their ClientID until November 2015, but Instagram seem to have made it so that we have to get users to log in so we can get an access token to use in the API call.

This seems nonsense and I can't help feeling I'm missing something simple.  I should be able to display client's content on their website without viewers of the site having to log into Instagram!

There are a number of solutions on Stack Overflow, but all the ones I've found pre-date Nov. 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own access_token.

Get it one time, save it and use it, it is not eternal though. I have the same problem.